# How far back in time does FAA Institutional Authority for 61.160 (R-ATP) minimums go?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, flight-school, atpl

[61.160](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=81f41e2efbe42e27fcf96ae9e6382f27&mc=true&node=se14.2.61_1160&rgn=div8) contains the requirements for an R-ATP certificate, and there is a [list of FAA approved institutions that are eligible to graduate applicants to meet the R-ATP requirements](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/training/atp/media/Institutional_Authority_List.pdf).

There is a column with issue and revision dates:
[image]

The increased qualification requirements were enacted in August 2013, and therefore these schools' LOAs are all issued after that date.

If a pilot had graduated from one of these schools' programs prior to the issuance of the LOA, does it still grant them the eligibility for reduced minima?  Is the authority retroactive?  If so, by how much time?

Comment: I expect the answer to your question is in the LOA. LOAs are unique to the authorized entity. While they are similar, they can vary significantly. Thus the notes at the bottom of the list.  Specifically: _Contact your institution for more information concerning their authorization._  and the following: NOTE: Institutions that do not wish to include a certifying statement on their graduate’s official transcript must include the certifying statement in a separate document. This document must be submitted as part of the application.